# Add/remove class with jquery based on vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to add class after 1070  i have the code for that and its work great:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      
     if (scroll >= 1070) {
  $(".header-main").addClass("extrablack");
     } else {
  $(".header-main").removeClass("extrablack");
     }
 });
});
```

now i need to add class extrablack in 1070 but remove in 1580 how can i do that? I need the class stay between 1070 and 1580 of website.
thanks

Comment: sorry this doesn't work.

Comment: `if (scroll >= 1070 && scroll < 1580)` then add class else remove it (important the else part)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef your condition is an impossibility

Comment: i need to add class in 1070 and after 1580 remove. this is impossibility?

Comment: sorry @Vachos my bad .. I don't know how I saw 1070 bigger then 1580 .. I need to change my Ophthalmologist :-) .. sorry again .. Good Luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      
     if (scroll >= 1070 && scroll < 1580) {
  $(".header-main").addClass("extrablack").text(scroll);
     } else {
  $(".header-main").removeClass("extrablack").text(scroll);
     }
 });
});
```

```css
.header-main{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center
}

.header-main.extrablack{
  background: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-main"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 1070 && scroll <= 1580) {
          $(".header-main").removeClass("extrablack");
          return;
        }

        if (scroll >= 1070) {
          $(".header-main").addClass("extrablack");
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't work. this add class but dont remove it.

Comment: @Vachos try it now